# External HD defrag stuck at 0% consolidated - due to discrepancy?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, chkdsk, veracrypt

I have an Acer laptop running windows 10.

I have tried multiple times to defragment my external Hard Drive (Seagate) but every time it gets stuck 0% consolidated.

I have run CHKDSK and I am posting the log below - can you please help?

I also have another question, due to a weird discrepancy which I am posting below

**CHKDSK**

```
Chkdsk was executed in read/write mode. 
 
Checking file system on E:
The type of the file system is NTFS.
Cannot lock current drive.
 
Chkdsk cannot run because the volume is in use by another
process.  Chkdsk may run if this volume is dismounted first.
ALL OPENED HANDLES TO THIS VOLUME WOULD THEN BE INVALID.
Would you like to force a dismount on this volume? (Y/N) 
Volume dismounted.  All opened handles to this volume are now invalid.
Volume label is Seagate Expansion Drive.
 
Stage 1: Examining basic file system structure ...
  380928 file records processed.                                                         
File verification completed.
 Phase duration (File record verification): 20.22 seconds.
  7 large file records processed.                                     
Phase duration (Orphan file record recovery): 0.00 milliseconds.
  0 bad file records processed.                                       
Phase duration (Bad file record checking): 0.23 milliseconds.
 
Stage 2: Examining file name linkage ...
  1612 reparse records processed.                                         
389794 index entries processed.                                                        
Index verification completed.
 Phase duration (Index verification): 24.69 seconds.
  0 unindexed files scanned.                                          
Phase duration (Orphan reconnection): 81.95 milliseconds.
  0 unindexed files recovered to lost and found.                      
Phase duration (Orphan recovery to lost and found): 2.25 milliseconds.
  1612 reparse records processed.                                        
Phase duration (Reparse point and Object ID verification): 13.73 milliseconds.
 
Stage 3: Examining security descriptors ...
Security descriptor verification completed.
 Phase duration (Security descriptor verification): 17.87 milliseconds.
  4434 data files processed.                                             
Phase duration (Data attribute verification): 1.46 milliseconds.
CHKDSK is verifying Usn Journal...
  40686520 USN bytes processed.                                                            
Usn Journal verification completed.
 Phase duration (USN journal verification): 1.23 seconds.
 
Windows has scanned the file system and found no problems.
No further action is required.
 
 976760032 KB total disk space.
 721606012 KB in 375953 files.
    188680 KB in 4435 indexes.
         0 KB in bad sectors.
    516480 KB in use by the system.
     65536 KB occupied by the log file.
 254448860 KB available on disk.


      4096 bytes in each allocation unit.
 244190008 total allocation units on disk.
  63612215 allocation units available on disk.
Total duration: 46.28 seconds (46280 ms).
```

**DISCREPANCY**

When I right click on the HD and click Properties, it says there are **739,660,513,280 bytes** of used space, and 260,541,759,488 of free space for a combined total of 1,000,202,272,768 bytes (see screenshot attached).

However, this is not consistent with the result given by Chkdsk.

Whereas the results provided by CHKDSK is identical when it comes to combined total space (CHKDSK returns 97,6760,032 KB i.e. 1,000,202,272,768 bytes, which is the exact same figure), it returns different figures when it comes to free space and used space.  Indeed, Chkdsk result for free space is 254,448,860 KB (which is 260,555,632,640 bytes) and for used space is 722,311,172 KB (which is **739,646,640,128 bytes**)

This would not be a problem because the difference is minimal (even though I'd still be curious to understand why there's difference). However, the problem arises when I go into the drive and do select all files to check how much space they occupy on the hard drive. When I CTRL+A and select properties, the result shows that all files on the drive (including all hidden files and even system files like the recycle bin) only occupy 724,257,847,343 bytes of space (size)  or **724,929,355,776 bytes** (size on disk). This is not at all a negligible result - we are talking about more than 15GB discrepancy. How can this be explained?

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: You did backup the VeraCrypt volume, right? RIGHT?

Comment: I’m not sure about your question? You mean I should have backed up a veracrypt volume on another hard drive? I am thinking that the 15 GB discrepancy may be due to the fact that there is data on the HD that is not showing up. I haven’t used this HD in some time. As you can see from the screenshot, I had installed a program called veracrypt which is used to encrypt data. Maybe there’s a Veracrypt volume or partition on the drive that contains data but for some error is not showing up? why is chkdsk showing a higher space usage than the one that comes up when I manually CTRL+A/properties?

Comment: Is there a way to understand whether there is any encrypted data on the hard drive? Perhaps the veracrypt volume has gone missing?